# Get the message of manually thrown exception

Tags: c#, exception

I'm deliberately throwing an exception for a particular scenario, but I would implicitly like to get the error message in string format. I'm aware that one of the overloads for the following exception is `string message`, but how do I access that string?

Here is the relevant snippet:

```
string errMsg;

private void Compress()
{
    if (sourcePath.EndsWith(".zip"))
    {
        throw new FileLoadException
                   ("File already compressed. Unzip the file and try again.");
        errMsg = //I want the above string here
    }
}
```

Comment: that code is unreachable "errMsg = //I want the above string here"

Comment: As you mentioned it already in a comment that you are new to error handling. One thing you should think about is if you really need an exception at that location (if its in the same if where you need to catch it then the question is if its really an exception you want or "just" a srting errMsg that is to be set)

Comment: @Thomas I would say no, it's not needed, but all my current projects are also about learning C# - which is inclusive of learning how to handle errors. Ideally, I'd just break the function off with the string, yes.

Comment: Like I said the comment was there as you are new to exception handling. I already thought that an exception is not needed in this case and wanted to mention it as you are in the learning process of when and where to use/raise exceptions and when/where not. That one thought process mentioned is what I always ask myself when I use an exception "do I really need an exception there or just a string". Exceptions are only needed if you want the calling process to know that something happened and you need to stop processing of the called method immediately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean this:?

```
try
{
    throw new FileLoadException
               ("File already compressed. Unzip the file and try again.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    errMsg = ex.GetBaseException().Message;
}
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Forgive me if this was a stupid question, the teaching content I used to learn C# didn't cover much error handling.

Comment: @Wolfish One lesson though: There is NO stupid question. You didn't know something and asked not more not less and that is what stackoverflow is about to ask questions you dont know/find the answers for.

Comment: @Wolfish let me say it so: Most downvoters don't even tell the reasons WHY they downvoted (thus I get the feeling that some ppl just downvote for the sake of it). The ones who give a reason I take into consideration and modify my question accordingly (or my answer if its an answer that gets downvoted). The others who dont give a reason I just tend to ignore as there is nothing that points to what I could do to do the question better (its most often only formal things that are wrong like no code example,....

Comment: thus it is still the same the question itself is not stupid only the implementation can be flawed)

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the string THERE I'll explain a bit there:

```
string errMsg;

private void Compress()
{
    if (sourcePath.EndsWith(".zip"))
    {
        throw new FileLoadException
                   ("File already compressed. Unzip the file and try again.");
        // The following line is unreachable as the throw ends the function and gets the exception to the calling function as there is no try catch block to catch the exception.
        errMsg = //I want the above string here
    }
}
```

A possibility would be to `try/catch` the exception in the method where you want to set the variable:

```
private void Compress()
{
    if (sourcePath.EndsWith(".zip"))
    {
        try
        {
            throw new FileLoadException
                       ("File already compressed. Unzip the file and try again.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errMsg = e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Or to catch the exception in the calling method instead:

```
try
{
    Compress();
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

regardless of method used the e.Message gives you the message of the exception as a string.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point to try catch the exception and set the message. Unless you re-throw it

```
try
{
    throw new FileLoadException("File already compressed. Unzip the file and try again.");

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    errMsg = ex.GetBaseException().Message;
    throw;
}
```

I would rather do this

```
private void Compress()
{
    if (sourcePath.EndsWith(".zip"))
    {
        errMsg = "File already compressed. Unzip the file and try again.";
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll bear this in mind for future projects. This project, though, is also about teaching myself which is why I'm exploring functions and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I 100% understand but if you want the message from that exception you can catch it and examine the Exception.Message

```
        try
        {
            throw new FileLoadException("Custom error string");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here should be an solution for you :)

```
        if (sourcePath.EndsWith(".zip"))
        {
            FileLoadException ex = new FileLoadException("File already compressed. Unzip the file and try again.");
            errMsg = ex.ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(errMsg);
```

To throw the exception that you made I would do soemthing like this

```
    static string sourcePath = "test.zip"; //hardcoded file
    static string errMsg; //the error string

    private static void Compress()
    {
        try
        {

            if (!sourcePath.EndsWith(".zip"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File doesn't end with zip so it can be compressed"); //if it does not end with zip its rdy for compressing and here you can indput your code to compress
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(); //instead of using try catch you can also generate the code in here instead of throwing an exception.
                                       //when throwing a new exception you make it stop the if setting and jump into the catch if you use break it wont enter the catch but instead it will just jump over it.
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
            //Here it will generate the custom exception you wanted and put it inside the errMsg
            errMsg = new FileLoadException("File already compressed. Unzip the file and try again.").ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(errMsg);
        }
```

ofc this is made in console that is why I use the console.writeline you can just change those out

Comment: What about throwing exception, not just creating it?

Comment: normally I would use a try catch like all the above is using but I just understood your question as that you wanted the fileloadexception to be in your errMsg and this simply does it? cant be rewrote to be just in one line also but made it so you would understand it.
if you arent going to get a crash in your if then it wont enter the catch so if you use a if it will just check if the file ends with zip it will never go into the catch.
basicly I will edit it with a new how I would throw the expetion